# HttpClient not send token in service context

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, angular-httpclient

I build an Angular 11 application using Msal package for security.

An interceptor provided by Msal add automatically the required Authorization header with the token.
But it works only when I use the HttpClient provided to a component. If I use the HttpClient injected to a service, the Authorization header is not set.

Everything goes like if the Http interceptor is executed only for component.

The structure of my app is vanilla:

- app

  - components

    - myComponent
  - shared

    - services

      - myService
        Component have dedicted module and service too. I've tried to declare my service in providers section of app.module and/or service.module but no luck.
        All modules are imported in app.module

Any ideas?

Edit
My app module imports:

```
imports: [

BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
LayoutModule,


// Msal Module
MsalModule,
HttpClientModule,
...
]
```

HttpClientModule is not imported elsewhere

The caller class:

```
export class GameListComponent {
 games: Game[];
 constructor(private gameService: GameService,
 private http: HttpClient) { }

 service() { // Token not sent
    this.gameService.list().subscribe(response=>{
       this.games = response;
       console.log(this.games);
    });
 }
 list() { // Token is correctly sent

   this.http.get("https://localhost:5001/api/Game/All")
    .subscribe(list=>console.log(list));
   }
 }
}
```

The service:

```
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GameService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 list():Observable<Game[]> {
  return this.http.get<Game[]>("api/Game/All");
 }
}
```

Edit 2:
I've forgot to mention that there are a proxy.conf on my app.

In case of the service, the proxy.conf is used and the call is done on the correct port but **without authorization header**.

If I call the API with the full address+port, the proxy is not used and the aithorization header is added (and the call succeed).

Still looking what is wrong...

Comment: Are you importing HttpClientModule only at app.module.ts?  If you import HttpClientModule again in another module, a new instance of HttpClientModule will be created. If so, that's probably why the interceptor is not working. You need to import at app.module.ts only.

Comment: @RobL. Don't change anything

Answer (score 0):

putting services in a shared module is a mistake, because injector is created for every lazy loaded module, and, in your case some services got duplicated. More common aproach is to put services into the `/core` module, which is imported only once - to the main app module.

Comment: At the moment, my modules are not lazy-loaded, and if I don't import the `services.module` in `app.module`, it doesn't change anything

Comment: it seems you are importing HttpClientModule more than once, or providing the module with interceptor not in the same injector as the http one. also there is a possibility, that interceptor works, but you don't have token at the moment of first requests, and it is not added because of that